# Change pagestyle to plain for first page of an unnumbered chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr

I'm writing my undergrad senior-thesis (at a German university) with the following specifications:

```
\documentclass[12pt,headsepline,footsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} }
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1}{} }
\fancyhead[LO]{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\thechapter}
\usepackage{apacite}
...
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}...\end{titlepage}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter*{List of Abbreviations}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}
...
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

\chapter{Introduction}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
...
...
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{references}
```

Almost everything is working now, only one problem remains: the "list of figures" and "list of tables" chapters use pagestyle plain and appear in the TOC; however, the list of abbreviations (which I created with `\chapter*` because I don't want it to be numbered) uses the full header both on the first and the second page (which is not perfect but acceptable), plus it puts "LIST OF TABLES" in the header, i.e. the wrong name and in capital letters, even though all the other chapter-names in the headers are written in small letters (thanx to the `\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} }
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1}{} }` commands). 
Also, for the references chapter, which is created automatically by the `apacite`-package, the word "REFERENCES" in the header is written in capital letters.
Does anyone know how I can change those two things?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Most of the things you've described are not reproducible with your [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is if you add more info.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use the `scrbook` class, rather than resorting to low level tricks like `\pagenumbering`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,headsepline,footsepline,oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhead[R]{\thechapter}

\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite} % the bibliography is a chapter

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}...\end{titlepage}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{List of Abbreviations}

\chapter{Abstract}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}

\nocite{*} % to populate the bibliography

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

In my experiment, no word in the header is capitalized.

You probably have to better customize the parameters for `fancyhdr`.

Answer (score 0):

For the references title you should try the following command

```
\renewcommand{bibname}{References}
```

(or whatever you want instead of "References") after the command

```
\usepackage{apacite}
```

For the list of abbreviations header, just add

```
\markboth{List of Abbreviations}{}
```

after the `\chapter*` command and it should work.